# Is there a Latin word for 225th anniversary?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request, noun, numbers

If bicentennial is the Latin word for the 200th anniversary, what word would one use for the 225th anniversary?

Answer (score 14):

"Bicentennial" is not actually Latin; it's just English. It doesn't even come from a Latin word. In particular, [bicentennial](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bicentennial#etymonline_v_11119) is an Americanism, and the more common word in England was (is still?) "bicentenary."

Presuming you don't want an actual Latin word, but an English word based on Latin roots, we can still make one up. "Bicentennial" comes from three chief Latin roots: *bi-*, meaning "two" or "twice," *-cent-* making "hundred," and "-enni-", from the Latin word *annus* meaning "year."

In Latin, a two-year period was called a "biennium," while a three-year period was known as a "triennium."

From these two arose a pattern in antiquity using the -enni- root, and later a period of ten years was coined using that pattern, yielding [*decennium*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Ddecennium).

Since English doesn't have proper case endings, we usually drop Latin's and adopt an adjectival ending, in this case -al, taken I presume on analogy from the Latin *annualis*, while that word literally means "one year old" in Latin, it was re-interpreted in English to mean "once a year."

From this pattern, modern writers coined the words "centennial" and, adding the bi- prefix, "bicentennial" (although in Latin "two hundred" is actually *ducenti*). The Latin for twenty-five is vigintiquinque, so you could theoretically have the monstrous **bicentetvigintiquinquennial**. I'm not personally a fan of this (or "bicentennial" for that matter), but I can imagine a technical type being attracted to it.

--
In the comments, Adam points out [Semiquincentennial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Semiquincentennial) for 250th anniversary. The formation is instead "half" (semi-) "500" (quincent-). Perhaps **quadrantinongentennial** (one-fourth of 900 years) might be a more suitable formation. But as you can see from the variations listed in the Wikipedia article, there is no one way of saying this, and people are just making it up.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that the familiar "millennium" is from that same series of words, although probably not an ancient coinage.

Comment: Also of note, apparently [Semiquincentennial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Semiquincentennial) was coined at some point.

Comment: Sesquicentennial is also frequently used for 150 years. From etymonline: sesqui-, sesque- "one and a half; one-half more," contraction of *semis-que- "a half in addition," from *semis "a half" (see semi-) + -que "and". Latin semi- had a tendency to get partly swallowed in compounds; [...] selibra "half a libra," semodius "half a modius," sestertius "having the value of two-and-a-half"

Comment: @NickT That's a good one, too. I hadn't thought about sesqui, so I might adopt that in a revision.

Comment: "bicentetvigintiquinquennial" -- Gesundheit!

Comment: I don't get 'sestertius' being 2.5, as I see it as semi-tertius, which could either be 1.5 or 3.5. Anyways, torturing [quasquicentennial](https://www.jstor.org/stable/454178) into such a format you could get quassecuntennial? Quasbicentennial? Ick. From the man who coined quasquicentennial: "Of course, you may decide you do not really want or need a new word. There is no point in proliferating them needlessly."

Comment: @NickT Yes! Yes! He echoes my thoughts precisely.

Comment: @cmw also Fowler's dictionary, as in the definition of centenary/centennial: "shots made at [...] higher names often [result] in monstrosities" (added more of the quote in my answer)

Comment: "so you could theoretically have the monstrous **bicentetvigintiquinquennial** [...]" → _Laughs in Spanish_

Comment: (PS: in Spanish, 225th **is** said "bicentesimovigesimoquinto" -- though it is written as separate words: "bicentésimo vigésimo quinto".)

Comment: @walen Yeah, even in English, the number itself is a cumbersome "two hundred and twenty-five." I think it's the compounding that makes it truly unwieldy.

Comment: @cmw My "laugh" came from the fact that, in Spanish, an event that happens once every 225 years would actually be, _I think_, a "**bicentevicequinquenal**" event -- no spaces. Pretty close to the "monstrous" English version! That was meant to be my original PS... but then I realized that 1) rules for the formation of this type of words in Spanish are not as clear cut as for everything else (might make for a good question @ [spanish.se]), and 2) OP didn't really ask about the word for something that _repeats_ every 225 years, they just wanted to know the (more boring) ordinal number for 225 :(

Answer (score 3):

One Frank W. Hatten of Delvan, Illinois wrote to [Funk & Wagnalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funk_%26_Wagnalls) (an American publisher known for reference works) in 1961, who relayed the letter to [Robert Chapman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_L._Chapman):

> Dr. Wilfred Funk has passed your letter of July 11 on to us. We are happy to help, if you feel that you really want a new Latinate word meaning "one hundred and twenty-fifth anniversary"
>
> The best model upon which to form the word is "sesquicentennial," meaning "one hundred and fiftieth anniversary." We need a first element meaning "plus a fourth," analogous with "sesqui" which means "plus a half".
>
> "Sesqui" is apparently formed from "semis que," meaning "and a half." How, both "quarta" and "quadrans" mean "a fourth," so we may begin with either "quarta que" or "quadrans que."
>
> The trick is to combine and shorten one of these as "sesqui" was combined and shortened from "semis que." If we follow the model of "sesqui" very closely, retaining the stressed vowel and final "s" of "quadrans," we get the word "quasquicentennial." Combining and shortening in other ways we can also get "quadqui-," "quansqui-," "quarsqui-," and perhaps several others.
>
> On the grounds that it is closest to the model and also probably the least ugly of the set, I would choose "quasquicentennial" (pronounced kwahskwee-) as the new word.

So, naively, I think one could extend quasquicentennial to perhaps **quasquibicentennial**.

> Of course, you may decide that you do not really want or need a new word. There is no point in proliferating them needlessly.

which is perhaps the best solution :)

> I should add, perhaps, that this word would not appear in any of our dictionaries until it has established itself in wide currency, even if you should decide to use it.

This word now does appear in Merriam-Webster, though I don't see when it was actually added.

> I hope we have been able to help you.
>
> — Chapman, Robert L. (1965) ["The history of Quasquicentennial"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/454178) American Speech
> Vol. 40, No. 1

Looking in Google Books, however, maaaaybe some other people were [using it in before](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Great_Lakes_News_Letter/OfMPxbvESwoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22quasquicentennial%22&dq=%22quasquicentennial%22&printsec=frontcover), but that snippet revealed mentions the 125th of something started in 1841 = 1966. Most other results I get seem to be mis-dated, as they came out in the mid 60s.

---

Towards the "centennial" vs. "centenary" and "not everything needs a word", the definition of "centenary, centennial" in the 1926/7 version of [Fowler's Dictionary of Modern English Usage](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.158217) (p. 72):

> **centenary, centennial**, nn. meaning hundredth anniversary. *Centenary*, the usual British form, has the disadvantage that the notion of years is not, except by modern development, contained in it; this, however, is true also of *century*, and need not count for much. *Centennial*, chiefly used (as a noun) in America, has the disadvantage that it gives a less convenient pattern for forming the names of higher anniversaries on. As these are sometimes wanted, it is worth while to maintain *centenary*.
>
> The ***shots made at these higher names often resulting in monstrosities*** [emph. added], a list of not intolerable forms is here offered. *Bicentenary*, which might have been *ducenary*, & *tercentenary* (*trecenary*), must be taken as established; but *quatercentenary* and *quincentenary* need not.

Comment: Good find! I still hate all these words, but this one looks like it has some common currency.

Comment: But a quarter of 200 is 50...

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I think if quasquicentennial is "a quarter and one centennial", "quasquibicentennial" can be "a quarter and two centennials", or would you suggest "quastercentennial" by way of "sestersi" (2.5), "quasterci" (2.25, or should it be 2.75)? In any event, we're not really talking Latin, but Latinate as Chapman mentions.

Comment: Yeah, @SebastianKoppehel, the discussion above was lovely but slightly off. It's not multiplication. It's addition: "one half and a ~". 225% is a weird fraction to be looking for but the classical model would be to use "one quarter and two ~".